# Cannot send BTC. "Insufficient funds"

Tags: copay

Yesterday I've sent transaction from my 2-of-4 Multi-sig wallet in Copay for Mac.
Transaction was signed by me and 1 more user. 
It was broadcasted to Blockchain (As Copay says).
But when I copy TX ID and search it on Blockchain.info or Insight - i see "No transaction found" message.

For now, I cannot create new transaction from this wallet because I receive an error "Insufficient funds".

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you past the txid here? This will sacrifice some privacy, but may help someone answer your question. It sounds like your tx might not have been broadcast.

Comment: d13421b4bd5a2ad215ab3349d9baa3ff220143faa0a5d7000e70bd18b1e2dfd2
Here it is.

Comment: If you can get the raw transaction hex, you can broadcast it yourself with a transaction broadcast api like https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx/.

Comment: @AndrewChow seems like I cannot get TX raw from the Copay :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was self-fixed. Frozen Transaction just disappeared.